# Reject Git commit if test coverage was less than a defined parameter

Tags: git, unit-testing, continuous-integration, tdd, code-coverage

Is it possible to integrate a Git repository with a CI server, that will be measure test coverage and some other parameters, and if there is not enough tests, or lot of non-DRY code, then reject the commit?

Answer (score 2):

TeamCity's pre-tested commit or delayed commit comes into mind - http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/delayed_commit.html

That is probably the best solution. Alternatively, you can look at having a git `pre-receive` hook which will reside on the Git server and reject commits that don't meet certain conditions. But it is not ideal to do stuff like running a whole build on the server.

Another alternative is to have developers set up a `pre-push` hook. This is more of a safety net, and doesn't prevent someone form pushing broken commits. But I suppose the safety net is all that is needed.

Comment: `pre-push hooks` looks like a pretty simple and interesting idea. Thanks. I'm not very professional in git, but is it possible to write come kind of commit script, and only commit's from this scripts should be accepted, but if user just try to make pure git commit - than it will be declined?